# update-rc.d: warning: start and stop actions are no longer supported; falling back to defaults

Tags: systemd, services

I have recently installed snmpd on my Ubuntu 16.04 VM. I was trying out few things and at some point I wanted to restart  the application using

`service snmpd restart`

It did not work, giving the message `undefined symbol: smux_listen_sd` 
I serched the internet for a possible reasons, but the main solution I was given was that there is another installed version that I need to remove. I looked for previous versions, there was nothing.

So after couple of uninstallations and re installations, it now works.

However, at the end of the installation, I noticed the message:

`update-rc.d: warning: start and stop actions are no longer supported; falling back to defaults`
`update-rc.d: warning: stop runlevel arguments (1) do not match snmpd Default-Stop values (0 1 6)`

Does that mean I can no longer use `service ... start`  or `systemctl ... start`?
If so, how should I start and stop an app?

Answer (score 1):

The "start" and "stop" arguments are deprecated!
Roger Leigh (Debian developer team) [announced that in debian-devel](http://lists.debian.org/debian-devel/2013/05/msg01109.html), on May 2013:

> the options still exist, but they
>     just invoke the "defaults" action.

As you can see in an extract of [update-rc.d(8) manpage](https://manpages.debian.org/jessie/sysv-rc/update-rc.d.8.en.html):

> The correct way to disable services is to configure the service as stopped in all runlevels in which it is started by default.

Comment: I noticed they still exists (the options) but they only produce an error when I'm using them with the snmp service... I've searched for quite some time, did not find an answer to that. Giving me headaches...

Comment: update-rc.d install and remove System-V style init script links into the boot sequence.. You can still use it with defaults and remove options but it is still for the boot sequence! systemctl start / stop is not in boot sequence..

Comment: Some info that might be important are over here: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/pkgreport.cgi?maint=team%2Bresolvconf%40tracker.debian.org